# NGRX Preventing an Infinite Loop Using CombineLatest

Tags: angular, ngrx

My Angular project has an NGRX Store which holds the state for `plan`. My `plan` object includes an array of locations called `locations`. I subscribe to an RXJS `combineLatest` to watch for changes to several values including `locations`. If any of the values change I perform various calculations and need to save the updated `locations` to the NGRX Store.

I cannot prevent an infinite cycle whereby a value in my `combineLatest` changes, calculations are performed, a new `plan` is created and a new array of `locations` are created named `updatedLocations` (as these are both immutable), I update the values in some of the `locations`, `updatedPlan.locations = updatedLocations`, and finally dispatch an action to update `plan` in the Store. However my `combineLatest` sees that `plan.locations` has changed and the whole process starts again.

A summary of the code is as follows:

```
  private locations$: Observable<ILocation[]> = this.store.pipe(select(fromPlan.getLocations)).pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  private foo$...
  private bar$...

    this.locationSubscription = combineLatest(
      this.locations$,
      this.foo$,
      this.bar$
    ).subscribe(
      ([locations, foo, bar]) => {
        // Create new Locations so I can change values.
        const updatedLocations = [...locations.map(l => ({ ...l }))]

        // Perform calculations

        // Update the Plan
        const updatedPlan = { ...this.plan };
        updatedPlan.locations = updatedLocations;
        this.store.dispatch(new planActions.SetPlan(updatedPlan));

      }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because you are storing derived state which is an antipattern - see 'Duplicate/derived state' at https://medium.com/@m3po22/stop-using-ngrx-effects-for-that-a6ccfe186399

Essentially, `updatedLocations` is derived from other state, so you should:

- store `locations`, `foo`, `bar` in your state as you do now
- create a selector which calculates the updated locations from those 3 lists

```
const selectUpdatedLocations = createSelector(
    selectLocations,
    selectFoo,
    selectBar,
    calculateUpdatedLocations
);

function calculateUpdatedLocations(locations, foo, bar){
     // Create new Locations so I can change values.
     const updatedLocations = [...locations.map(l => ({ ...l }))];
     return updatedLocations;
}
```

I suspect something similar will apply to `Plan`- ie: use a selector to build up the Plan from information in the state and `selectUpdatedLocations`, rather than storing the Plan itself.

Comment: This is really interesting and changes my perspective on Selectors, thank you. The calculations which are performed when one of the 3 list values changes are long and complex. Can I call a service to perform most of the heavy lifting and then have my Selector return the result?

Comment: Yes, you can call a service or function but it shouldn't really be doing any I/O etc. Due to memoization in the selector, your heavy lifting will only be executed when the inputs change, and the result cached.

Comment: Great, I would prefer to keep my Selectors clean to read. The function in the Service just iterates over the various associated values (foo, bar) and performs various mathematical calculations ultimately just updating some properties of the `locations`.

Comment: It appears that I can't (and shouldn't) inject a Service into my Reducer. From what I read I should call an Action which will trigger an Effect. I can't fathom it though! Are you able to provide some more clarity please?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your logic has side effects so don't use an Effect - just change your service into a normal function and call it like I have shown in the modified answer.

Comment: I see that, but it doesn't feel right to have so much business logic in my Reducer (there are many other Selectors which have the same problem). This all comes after updating from Angular/NGRX 7 to 10 and the stricter checking of immutability.

Comment: Correct, you should have minimal business logic in your reducers. You may have mixed your terminology, but this logic is now in a selector - selectors are not reducers. IMO selectors are well suited for this purpose as it keeps the reducers simpler and memoization reduces the overhead. In any case, it is a vastly better organisation of state than you started with.

Comment: Ah, of course. I have a single class `plan.reducer.ts` which has Selectors at the top and Reducers below. Now the application has grown perhaps I should split them apart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222380/discussion-between-tdc-and-wlf).